# App crash on iOS7 but runs fine with iOS6

Tags: crash, ios7

While troubleshooting a crash that was only happening on iOS7 (iOS6 was fine), the application crashed several times on a line that wasn't helping with the troubleshooting, but eventually crashed once on a line like `[object release]`.

After I removed the offending line, the crash disappeared.

Old code:

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
[imageView release];
imageView = nil;
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

New code:

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
//[imageView release];
imageView = nil;
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

The stack was showing the crash here: `objc_msgSend ()`

I would appreciate if someone could explain why it was crashing on iOS7 with the old code and what I was doing wrong?
Also I'd like to understand why it was not crashing with iOS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling NS Zombies to check that your aren't trying to over release it which it sounds like you are.. You should do a check to see if the imageView isn't nil before releasing it :)

I would recommend moving to ARC if you can though.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Enabling ARC solved my problems.